# How to force specific HTTP headers of cacheable resources served by Windows Azure Storage?

Tags: caching, azure, http-headers, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In the document ["Optimize Cache - Make the Web Faster - Google Developers"](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching), Google states that

> It is important to specify ONE of **Expires** or **Cache-Control
>   max-age**, AND ONE of **Last-Modified** or **ETag**, for all cacheable
>   resources. It is redundant to specify both Expires and Cache-Control:
>   max-age, or to specify both Last-Modified and ETag.

I'm using the classes in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient to upload images to a blob container, pratically the same code as can be seen in the open source project [Azure Storage Explorer](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/).

The resulting image is served with BOTH Last-Modified and ETag:

```
ETag: 0x8CFED5D3384112F
Last-Modified: Tue, 12 Mar 2013 17:21:43 GMT
```

So the next browser requests sends HTTP headers:

```
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 12 Mar 2013 17:21:43 GMT
If-None-Match: 0x8CFED5D3384112F
```

How can I force Azure Storage to use only one of the two directives to eliminate this redudancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you can't.

When thinking about this it's important to remember that when you access blob storage you not accessing a file on a web server, you're using a rest API that happens to return files.

Microsoft offer no way to remove headers that they deem as essential to the storage API.

If you're worried about excessive headers, the response also includes several x-ms-... headers which are intended for clients of the API that aren't browsers.

Comment: It's true Azure Storage sends several x-ms headers by default that will be ignored by the browsers.  But "Microsoft offer no way to configure the headers that are returned from any storage calls" it's not very true, as using Azure SDK I can control the presence or not of cache headers (the scope of my question), ContentEncoding, ContentMD5, ContentLanguage and some others I can control the value, like ContentType. Anyway, based on your answer and [little further search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179440.aspx), I'm going to let that alone.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not worry that much about both tags being send back as this is actually recommended by [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

> 13.3.4 Rules for When to Use Entity Tags and Last-Modified Dates
>   ...
>   HTTP/1.1 origin servers:
>   ...
>   ... **the preferred behavior for an HTTP/1.1 origin server is to send both *a strong entity* tag and a *Last-Modified* value.**

An HTTP 1.1 client **MUST** use the **Entity Tags** in any cache-conditional requests, and if both an **Entity Tags** and **Last-Modified** are present, it **SHOULD** use both.

I hope that will clarify why both tags are sent back from the Azure Storage server.

Comment: Thanks, very good catch and now I can keep on without worring! But analyzing by the "Make Web Faster" side, I still tend to agree with Google's argument of redundancy and still would like to find a solution.